# Group statuses together and sort within those status with 1 SQL call in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have a table `profiles` that have three notable fields: `price, rating and status`. So far I've figured out how to sort by rating in descending order, then sort by price in ascending order among records with the same rating with:

```
Profile.all.order('rating DESC, price ASC')
```

And vice versa by sorting price ascending then rating descending among records with the same price:

```
Profile.all.order('price ASC, rating DESC')
```

However, I have a column `status` that is of `integer` type with `enum [:pending, :verified, :rejected]. I would like to make 1 SQL call that first groups the records of`status: verified`and every other status (`rejected`and`pending`) after the`verified`group. Within the`verified` group, it would sort all records by rating DESC then price ASC or vice versa. Within the "other" group, it would do the same thing.

The end result will be 2 sorted lists where ALL `verified` records appear before the "other" records.

I could do `Profile.all.order('status DESC, rating DESC, price ASC')`, and rearrange `verified` to be the largest index in the `enum`, but I would like `rejected` and `pending` to be mixed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just think the query will be like:

```
Profile.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT id, rating, price
                                 FROM profiles
                                 WHERE status = 'verified'
                               ) AS temp ON temp.id = profiles.id")
       .order("temp.rating DESC NULLS LAST, temp.price ASC NULLS LAST, profiles.rating DESC, profiles.price ASC")
```

Explanation:

- After left outer join, we order by `temp.rating DESC NULLS LAST` that means we order by rating of profile which has `status = verified`, for profiles `status != verified`, their `temp.rating` and `temp.price` will be `NULL`, that is why `NULLS LAST` was using here
- The same idea for `temp.price`

Btw, you may change `WHERE status = 'verified'` to work with your case, because maybe `status = 1` for eg